# Message box displaying "2" but not "1" in C# code for audio conversion

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# code snippet that performs audio conversion using FFmpeg. The code includes two message boxes, one displaying "2" and another displaying "1". However, during runtime, only the message box with "2" is shown, while the one with "1" is not displayed. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
MessageBox.Show("2"); // This message box is displayed
ffmpegProcess.Start();
ffmpegProcess.WaitForExit();
ffmpegProcess.Close();
MessageBox.Show("1"); // This message box is not displayed
```

I've verified that the code for displaying the message box with "1" is not commented out and that there are no exceptions or errors reported. Strangely, the message box displaying "2" appears correctly before the code block where the message box with "1" is located.

I'm puzzled as to why the message box with "1" is not shown while the one with "2" appears correctly. I've checked the conditions and variables, and they seem to be in order. Are there any potential reasons or pitfalls that could prevent the message box with "1" from being displayed? Any suggestions for troubleshooting or further investigating this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Run it in a debugger with a breakpoint on the second `MessageBox.Show()`; does it hit the breakpoint? As `MessageBox.Show()` is modal, and assuming the app keeps running other things after the shown code, there’s almost certainly an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

There are two blocking calls before you get to where the second `MessageBox` would be displayed. The first one is the first call to `MessageBox.Show`, the second is `ffmpegProcess.WaitForExit();`. The things to check, then, are:

1. Are you actually closing the first `MessageBox`? `MessageBox.Show()` is [modal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), which means it blocks until the `MessageBox` is closed by the user
2. Is `ffmpegProcess` actually ever exiting?

Assuming you are closing the `MessageBox`, place a breakpoint on `MessageBox.Show("1");` and see if that code is ever actually reached. Seems likely that your ffmpeg job just isn't exiting.

One other thing to note; how long are you waiting for? You haven't said what you're doing with ffmpeg, but it could be a very long-running operation. It might just be the case that your ffmpeg job hasn't exited *yet.*